# Running a Jmeter *.JMX with more than one instance at a time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have a scenario, where the http request will be processed in a sequential order, i.e., the sessions from one response has to be passed as an input to another request. I completed the sequence. its working fine with single user.

When i try to run with more than one user (to perform load test), the requests which is getting executed faster overrides and collapses the sequential order. It results in failure.

My question is that whether any one tried running the *.JMX with more than one instance at a time. The sequential order will be running individually and the result *.JTL can either stored individually are grouped (not a problem).

Please suggest some ideas!!

Comment: Each jmeter thread works like virtual user, it keeps local variables unless you pass it between threads in some way. Does your test plan works well on second and subsequent cycles? I'd recommend you to find the reason why it breaks.

Comment: Dear F2nd, There are more parameters other than sessions, which I need be pass from one response to another request. I need to run more than one instance of the same *.JMX. which will run independently without affecting each other. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each JMeter thread executing samplers top down. The situation when different threads execute different samplers at the same moment is absolutely expected so given your correlation implementation is good you shouldn't see errors.

Few suggestions:

- Don't run several instances of .jmx file with several JMeter instances, consider increasing number of threads for single JMeter
- If you still need multiple instances for some reason - make sure you use **unique** data for each instance, i.e. if you parametrise usernames/passwords via [CSV Data Set Config](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config) - use different .csv files with different data for every JMeter
- In majority of cases it's quite enough to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)